# InvalidRegistration FCM response from a curl request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification to an android app, but I always receive an error saying "InvalidRegistration", I tried many solutions posted on stackoverflow and googled so much but with no progress!

Here's the curl command I use:

```
$ curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<SERVER KEY>"  -X POST -d '{ "data": { "score": "5x1","time": "15:10"}, "to" : "<APP KEY>"}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

and here's the response:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   216    0   122  100    94    122     94  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   445{"multicast_id":7321962376365265310,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Comment: Please update your question to include relevant client code. Thanks!

Comment: I am not working on the client code, but we tested it and sent notifications through the firebase and it worked. Do you think that this may be still because of the client code?

Comment: Invalid Registration means the token is not in the right format. Check on the push token you are using to send push